# How to use the bwwtrim function of the WRS package? (robust 3-way mixed ANOVA)

Tags: r, mixed-model, anova, robust, psychology

in our study, we look at the effects of typical/enhanced body checking on eating pathology  before and after the intervention, depending on the level of body concern (see below). Since the assumptions for a 3-way mixed ANOVA are not met, we'd like to conduct the robust alternative using the WRS package on R. There is a function called `bwwtrim` (function (J, K, L, data, tr=0.2, grp = c(1:p), alpha = 0.05, p=J * K *L) that seems to be what we need. However, I don't find any instruction on how to use it. In what format do the data need to be? How do I need to fill in the formula?
Here are the variables and factors we use:

Independent variables:

1. factor (between-subjects) = Body concern (high/low)
2. factor (within-subjects) = Condition (typical frequency / 3x increased frequency of Body Checking)
3. factor (within-subjects) = Time (pre / post intervention)

Dependent variable:
eg. Score on the "Drive for Thinness" questionnaire

For our 2-way mixed ANOVA (bwtrim function of the WRS2 package), I found a very helpful summary by the authors themselves (Robust Statistical Methods Using WRS2, Mair & Wilcox, https://rdrr.io/cran/WRS2/#vignettes). Is there something similar for the `bwwtrim` function?

Comment: I'd suggest asking directly the author(s) of the package...

Answer (score 1):

You can check out Section 8.8.2 of "Introduction to Robust Estimation
and Hypothesis Testing" 4th edition by Wilcox (2017). It contains the instructions & the function you should be able to get from the txt file in https://dornsife.usc.edu/labs/rwilcox/software/

I recently found this as I had to use bbwtrim - however it only gives the F value and p value, I am disappointed as I need confidence interval and effect size too :(

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/336575)